# WebSocket security of incoming connection to clients

Tags: websocket

I have written **WebSocket** server with **token** authentication where the client connects as:

```
socket = new WebSocket("wss://websockets", ["hub", token] )
```

It uses `subprotocol` to squeeze auth token within headers.

On the server side I intercept this header key and authorize the request which works great - the client connects ok and keeps the connection open. 
When token is not supplied, connection is rejected - great!

So in the typical use case: **chat application**, the user logins and gets authorization token to open the connection. Once connection is opened the client sends message to the server and the server sends that message to all connected clients.

So, so far I understand that the opening connection to the server and sending message to it is secured. **What happens when that message is pushed to all connected clients?** I don´t need to be concerned about authorization of incoming messages (to the client) since the client needs to be connected and therefore authorized to receive those messages right?

Comment: What is your security model? What are the requirements?

Comment: @curiousguy - Channel security is done over https (hence wss:// ). Authorization with JWT. Need to make sure that unauthorized users will not be able to send/recieve messages.

Comment: The use of HTTPS is an implementation choice not a security property. You need to make the desired properties explicit.

Comment: @curiousguy - What it has to do with my question?

Comment: Do you have a security related question? If so, you need to write down the requirements which aren't clear here.

Comment: @curiousguy - I think the question is clear enough. WebSocket (wss) + JWT authorization for establishing connection and sending messages to the server. How secure is pushing those messages to the client? Can somone setup fake WS server and push fake messages to the client?

Comment: Information is very incomplete. How is your website hosted? Is it complete HTTPS? Is the URL recognizable? Are users likely to be fooled if sent to a different URL?

Comment: @ArturKędzior HTTPS uses SSL/TLS for channel security, which in turn uses certificates to validate identity. If your real server has a valid certificate that clients can verify upon connecting, then clients that verify certificates won't be able to communicate with a fake server that doesn't have the real server's certificate. That is why it is important for clients to verify the certificate of the server they connect to.